# AUTO_INCREMENT causing syntax errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to set up the AUTO_INCREMENT at a certain value but I am having errors in syntax.  I am unsure what it is as I have looked at documentation and it seems ok.  However there must be an error.

EDIT - Sorry,  I am using mysql phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
 CUSTID              int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 109,
 NAME                CHAR (45),
 ADDRESS             CHAR (40),
 CITY                CHAR (30),
 STATE               CHAR (2),
 ZIP                 CHAR (9),
 AREA                NUMERIC(3),
 PHONE               CHAR (9),
 REPID               NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
 CREDITLIMIT         NUMERIC(9,2),
 COMMENTS            TEXT,
 CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (CUSTID),
 CONSTRAINT CUSTID_ZERO CHECK (CUSTID > 0));
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: sorry.  It is phpmyadmin

Comment: phpmyadmin is a tool, not a database engine. Looks like you're using MySQL. There are other tools to interact with a MySQL database.

Comment: In general, if you need to manipulate the auto-incremented value (i.e.if the value has any meaning beyond the internal scope of the database), you probably shouldn't be using AUTO_INCREMENT!!!

Answer (score 0):

#### To let the `AUTO_INCREMENT` sequence start with another value, you need to alter table separatelely.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
 CUSTID              int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 NAME                CHAR (45),
 ADDRESS             CHAR (40),
 CITY                CHAR (30),
 STATE               CHAR (2),
 ZIP                 CHAR (9),
 AREA                NUMERIC(3),
 PHONE               CHAR (9),
 REPID               NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
 CREDITLIMIT         NUMERIC(9,2),
 COMMENTS            TEXT,
 CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (CUSTID),
 CONSTRAINT CUSTID_ZERO CHECK (CUSTID > 0));

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER AUTO_INCREMENT= 109;
```

Comment: How does it know which column to auto increment?

Comment: We need to specify AUTO_INCREMENT  against  the column name in the create statement.

Comment: btw NOT NULL is not necessary for auto_incs

Comment: What if thee are two columns in the same table that both need to be AUTO_INCREMENTED starting at a specific value?

Comment: @Peta, you can refer to following post for 2 column auto_increment : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

This format works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUSTID              int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME                CHAR (45),
ADDRESS             CHAR (40),
CITY                CHAR (30),
STATE               CHAR (2),
ZIP                 CHAR (9),
AREA                NUMERIC(3),
PHONE               CHAR (9),
REPID               NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
CREDITLIMIT         NUMERIC(9,2),
COMMENTS            TEXT,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 109,
CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (CUSTID),
CONSTRAINT CUSTID_ZERO CHECK (CUSTID > 0));
```